# Access imageDownloadsInProgress in LazyTableImages

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, cocoa-touch

if I do any action on the imageDownloadsInProgress array, I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

For example:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

self.imageDownloadsInProgress = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
self.tableView.rowHeight = kCustomRowHeight;

// Set navigation items
UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd
                                                          target:self action:@selector(test)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
}

- (void)test {
NSLog(@"TEST: %@", self.imageDownloadsInProgress.count);
}
```

Is it about threading?

Comment: Well, first of all, you are not accessing a NSArray, you are initialising the imagesDownloadsInProgress as a NSMutableDictionary. Second, it will be useful to see your implementation of LazyTableImages, so we can help you better.

Comment: Hi, nothing's changed. It is the implementation from apple. all default. I only added the code above. And of course, it's an NSMutableDictionary.

Comment: Did you figured out yet?  I think the problem on is that you are trying to print an object in the NSLog but you are sending an NSInteger.  Change it to `NSLog(@"TEST: %d:", self.imageDownloadsInProgress.count);`

Answer (score 1):

I think the better question is "what are you trying to accomplish"  If you are needing a fast, efficient and multi-threaded option for getting images from an external source (Internet) and using them in a tableview cell without any UI lag, then Blocks are your friend.  I have a complete example class that I can put on here if you need me to.

Comment: For example, if I want to add refresh functionality, the datasource of course may change. that forces me to update imageDownloadsInProgress. and the app will crash then.

is there something like an refresh feature in your example class? Indeed I'm interested in that code your mentioned. Would you mind to put it on?